# Who to make IsolationForest more sensitive to single-feature outliers?

Tags: isolation-forest, pycaret

I am using IsolationForest with `pycaret`. I find that the algorithm identifies instances where many features are somewhat different, but when most features are normal and only a single, or a small number of features is anormal, the algorithm is not reliable to identify that. I wonder what hyperparameters could be changed in order to make the model more sensitive to single feature-outliers?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use single feature outlier detection in order to detect this. Because if only a single feature is extreme and another ones is one likely values a multivariate outlier detection algorithm is likely to assign a regular observation, instead a extreme one.